# Vuforia edit default script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm trying to use Vuforia to make an aplication that matches images for corresponding to a same group.
For example if the camera show a the image of a zebra stored and the image of a dog stored it should set a text saying correct, but if the camera catches the image of the zebra and the image of a car it should set a text saying error.
I have completed the camera camera recognition but i don't know to handle the code to avoid the default behavior.
I suppose i have to modify these part of the C# script

```
protected virtual void OnTrackingFound()
    {
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
        {

            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName);

            var rendererComponents = mTrackableBehaviour.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
            var colliderComponents = mTrackableBehaviour.GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
            var canvasComponents = mTrackableBehaviour.GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);


            // Enable rendering:
            foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
                component.enabled = true;

            // Enable colliders:
            foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
                component.enabled = true;

            // Enable canvas':
            foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
                component.enabled = true;
        }
    }


    protected virtual void OnTrackingLost()
    {
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
        {
            var rendererComponents = mTrackableBehaviour.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
            var colliderComponents = mTrackableBehaviour.GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
            var canvasComponents = mTrackableBehaviour.GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);

            // Disable rendering:
            foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
                component.enabled = false;

            // Disable colliders:
            foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
                component.enabled = false;

            // Disable canvas':
            foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
                component.enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

But i don't know how to do it, so if someone can help me giving ideas o the solution it will be apreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to create a new script attached to every marker you want to compare. For example:

```
public class MyMarker : MonoBehaviour
{
  public string markerName; //Can be edited in the inspector
}
```

Then you need to know that when Vuforia founds or losts a Marker, the GameObject is enabled or disabled.

You can have specific behaviour when found (enabled) or lost (disable) with the methods [OnEnable()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnEnable.html) and [OnDisable()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDisable.html).

```
public class MyMarker : MonoBehaviour
{
  public string markerName; //Can be edited in the inspector

  void OnEnable()
  {
    //The object is active
  }

  void OnDisable()
  {
    //The object is inactive 
  }
}
```

Also, you can know if a game object is active with [myGameObject.activeInHierarchy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeInHierarchy.html).

With this you now which markers are active.

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you for answering my question. I'm very new with vuforia and unity so I'll need you to be more specific on the answer.
First I would need to know where to put the script and when it would run.
I don't know if it should be on the imageTargets replacing the default trackable event handler, or adding an aditional Script but not touching the default trackable event handler or even if the script should be on the 3D objects that are asociated to each image target. In the other hand I don't know to display a 3D object using the code... Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Don't edit the default trackable event handler, and not remove it, it's essential.
You should attach "MyMarker" script in each of your image targets, to identified them.

Then you could have another script that manages if the markers are active or not.

You don't need to display a 3d object using code, usually you just need to make that object child of the image target.